# Method doesnt want to move to Generic Class

Tags: vb.net, generics

I am wrapping a COM API.
In general, I have had good luck designing some generic classes and shoving the tested parts down into those classes.

Here is one that is giving me a problem. 
There are classes that represent result sets. They do not inherit, they do implement a common interface, but it is a very simple interface. It does not expose the ResultSet functionality, specifically  .COUNT or .GetAt(i)

My workaround is to make this a MustInherit and use CodeSmith to do the work for me. Not the end of the world. 13 more lines of generated code per entity.

I have played around with a class that might bridge this, and an interface that might bridge this, but I keep coming back to the fact that there is no common 'thing' in the API that represents a result set.

I may be missing something, I certainly am not seeing the solution.

The code for one instance of the work around is listed below

I would like to move this function to the Generic. It currently sits in each instance of class that uses the generic.

ICustomerRetList inherits from IBase. IBase has neither .Count or .GetAt() as mentioned above.

**To be clear- My question is this :  Can you suggest a vb construct that will allow me to move this function from my concrete class, down to my generic class**

```
Public Overrides Function RetListToList(RetList As ICustomerRetList) As List(Of  Customer)
    Dim oItem As ICustomerRet
    Dim oItem As Customer
    Dim l As New List(Of  Customer)

    For idx = 0 To RetList.**Count** - 1    '.Count is not a member of IBase
        oqbItem = RetList.**GetAt**(idx)    '.GetAt() is not a member of IBase
        oItem = New  Customer()

        'add the  Item to the list
        Call l.Add(oItem)
    Next
    Return l
End Function
```

Comment: How is ICustomerRetList implemented? Why don't add these methods to that interface?

Comment: @Gosha, Thanks for the interest. this is a 3rd party API I am wrapping. It is not open to change. To answer the question , it is an COM Interface implemented inside a dll. Thanks again.

Comment: If they use the same name you could use an Extension Method that uses reflection to get the method from the runtime object type. Not sure that would be a better solution than generating it though.

Answer (score 1):

If all implementations of IBase have these methods, and they all have the same names, you could combine extension methods and reflection to effectively lower the functions.

```
Public Class CustomerRetListExtensions
    <Extension()> 
    Public Function GetAt(ByVal list As IBase, ByVal idx As Integer) As IBase
        Return DirectCast(list.GetType().GetMethod("GetAt").Invoke(list, New Object() { idx }), IBase)
    End Function
    ' If Count is a property, otherwise use the same approach as for GetAt
    <Extension()> 
    Public Function Count(ByVal list As IBase) As Integer
        Return DirectCast(list.GetType().GetProperty("Count").GetValue(list), Integer)
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I had not considered Extension methods. In this particular case, I am still grappling with the challenge that I have to cast to ICustomerRet, or IVendorRet, or.....  to get this to work. So I think I still have a block of code for each entity. Am I missing it? Given that, I think the more clear choice would be to stick with the straight forward routine.

Comment: The casting is where reflection comes in. `GetType()` gets the runtime type of the object, not the static type, so you can can then use `GetMethod()` to call the methods without casting.

Comment: Ok, so in your example above, can I use IBase at the return type of GetAt()  ?   what i want to shy away from is having to write ~80 sets of extension methods.  It becomes a matter of 2 roughly equivalent solutions at that point. Im not reducing the code I have to generate, just changing it.

Comment: Yes you can use IBase. I realized I forgot the casts as `Invoke()` has a return type of object.

Comment: @ user1937198, neither of these work. I think we are close though, should i put my code in my question or post an answer and put it there?

Comment: @ user1937198,   the code you suggested wont work because this is a COM DLL and it is late bound.  The only methods available are those on "___ComObject".   I am investigating  InvokeMember, the challenge is getting a runtime access to the type of the object.